# SFML using MingW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sfml

So I got SFML to work on my Mac using this line in my makefile:

```
g++ -I/Users/Junker/SFML/include -L/Users/Junker/SFML/lib main.cpp -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -      lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
```

I thought it would be more or less the same when using MingW on a windows machine but this does not work:

```
g++ -I"C:\SFML-2.1\include" -L"C:\SFML-2.1\lib" main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

For windows I downloaded the GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 64 bits version

The version for Mac is using .dylibs libraries, and the Windows version is using .a.

The code I try to get working is:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error test is a lot of undefined references to VideoMode, RenderWindow and a few others. Does it seems like there is a library, or parts of it that aren't correctly linked?

What other things should I apply to my compile line to get it to work?

Thanks for the help in advance!